# Symmetric, positive definite Matrix

Tags: matrices

When $\Omega$ is a symmetric, positive definite Matrix, why can a non-singular Matrix $P (n \times n)$ can be found such that
$\Omega = PP^{'}$
What is the logic behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symmetric $\implies$ orthogonally diagonalizable

Positive definite means all eigenvalues $\lambda_i >0$
Hint: Using this we get $A=PDP^T=PD^{1/2}D^{1/2}P^T=QQ^T$

Answer (score 1):

The decomposition is called the Cholesky decomposition. It works because of the following

$$  \Omega = \begin{bmatrix} \textbf{1} & w^{*} \\ w & K\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \textbf{1} & 0 \\ w & I \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \textbf{1} & w^{*}  \\  0 & K - 
 ww^{*}\end{bmatrix} $$

then we get  that

$$ \begin{bmatrix} \textbf{1} & w^{*}  \\  0 & K - 
 ww^{*}\end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix} \textbf{1} & 0   \\  0 & K - 
 ww^{*}\end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix} \textbf{1} & w^{*}  \\  0 & I\end{bmatrix} $$

Then we see that $ \Omega $ is given as

$$ \Omega = \begin{bmatrix} \textbf{1} & 0 \\ w & I \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \textbf{1} & 0   \\  0 & K - 
 ww^{*}\end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix} \textbf{1} & w^{*}  \\  0 & I \end{bmatrix} $$